# jQuery select value combination

Tags: jquery, filter, html-select

I'm currently working on a school project and need some help on my jQuery script. I want to filter a whole ranking system with < select > boxes.

I've got the following and it works

```
<select>
    <option value="all">All</option>
    <option value="cars">Cars</option
</select>

<div id="all" class="ranking-item">All rankings</div>
<div id="cars" class="ranking-item">Cars rankings</div>
```

With the jQuery

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    $(".ranking-item").not(":first").hide(); //prevent seeing nothing

    $("select").change(function() {

    $('.ranking-item').hide();
    var targetId = $(this).val();
    $('#'+targetId).show();
    })

});
```

But I want 1 more filter, like this

```
<select>
    <option value="all">All</option>
    <option value="cars">Cars</option
</select>

<select>
    <option value="lap1">Lap 1</option>
    <option value="lap2">Lap 2</option
</select>
```

Expected output would be

```
<div id="all lap1" class="ranking-item">All rankings</div>
<div id="all lap2" class="ranking-item">All rankings</div>
<div id="cars lap1" class="ranking-item">Cars rankings</div>
<div id="cars lap2" class="ranking-item">Cars rankings</div>
```

But this doesn't work...

Any guesses how I can get this to work?
Thanks in forward

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't have multiple ids. Ids are unique. Use classes instead.

```
    <select>
        <option value="all">All</option>
        <option value="cars">Cars</option>
    </select>

    <select>
        <option value="lap1">Lap 1</option>
        <option value="lap2">Lap 2</option>
    </select>

    <div class="ranking-item all lap1">All rankings lap1</div>
    <div class="ranking-item all lap2">All rankings lap2</div>
    <div class="ranking-item cars lap1">Cars rankings lap1</div>
    <div class="ranking-item cars lap2">Cars rankings lap2</div>

    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.0.0.min.js"></script>
    <script>

        $(document).ready(function() {

            $(".ranking-item").not(":first").hide(); //prevent seeing nothing

            $("select").change(function() {

                $('.ranking-item').hide();
                var targetClass = $(this).val();
                $('.'+targetClass).show();

            })

        });

    </script>
```

Also think about the logic behind it. If selects are used as filters you should filter all data list with all filters(or maybe reset others):

eg:

if all is selected, we get two elements of all
if lap is selected, we get two elements of lap(even though all is still selected)

Combine the filters so that if all and lap1 is selected it ouputs the right list.